# JNI NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null

Tags: java, android, reflection, java-native-interface

I am working on calling an instance method using `JNI` in `Android`. All code compiles, yet to protect the content of the project, I only will show relevant parts of the code. The following code block (`extern c` used in a *c++* file) attempts to access a static method [`public String getMyString()`] in *cls*. I know that *cls* and *env* are not null. *mid* is not set to zero, nor is it *null*. When this native method returns to the Java side, I get the following error (traced back to [Class.java](http://source-android.frandroid.com/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/lang/Class.java)):

```
02-22 10:38:36.010: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 10
02-22 10:38:36.010: E/AndroidRuntime(17894): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: parameter type is null
02-22 10:38:36.010: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at java.lang.ClassMembers.getConstructorOrMethod(ClassMembers.java:228)
02-22 10:38:36.010: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:904)
02-22 10:38:36.010: E/AndroidRuntime(17894):    at com.example.android.MyClass.getMyString(Native Method)
02-22 10:38:36.010: ...
```

The code that generates the error is as follows:

```
    jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getMyString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
    if (mid == 0) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", "mid is 0");
    }
    else {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", "mid is not 0");
    }
    jstr = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid);
    if (jstr == NULL) {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", "jstr is NULL");
    }
    else {
        __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "JNI", "jstr is not NULL");
    }

    printf("  c.s = \"%s\"\n", env->GetStringUTFChars(jstr, NULL));

    return jstr;
```

Although Class.java seems to suggest it is a problem with the cast from *null* to `Class<?>[]` (common for reflection), I have a feeling it has more to do with *mid* finding the wrong method or *jstr* coming back incorrectly (logcat states that *jstr* is NOT null).

Lastly, the Java-side relevant code is as follows:

The native call:

```
public static native String getMyNativeString();
```

The call to the native method:

```
String myStr = callGetMyNativeString();
```

The method that is being accessed:

```
public String getMyString() {
    return "Foobar";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure of this without seeing the full java code. But the native method is being defined as static, and the java method `getMyString()` is non-static. So from the JNI, how did  you get the `obj` needed to call `getMyString()`?